# Таймер при наведении на блок и обратный таймер после выхода курсора из области

Tags: javascript, таймер

Доброго времени суток.
Несколько часов "бьюсь" головой и думаю, как сделать, чтобы при наведении на блок запускался таймер, а после вывода курсора из блока запускался обратный
Т.е нужно
Чтобы при наведении на блок через секунду добавился класс number_1, через две number_2 и т.д. (это все легко решается с помощью setTimeout)
Но нужно чтобы если человек вывел курсор за область блока, начинался обратный отсчет
Т.е если последним было number_4, он начинал удалить классы, через 1 секунду number_4, через 2 number_3 и т.д

Comment: _это все легко решается с помощью setTimeout_

Comment: Можете показать пример? я понимаю, что это через setTimeout решается, но пока не могу понять как. Пробовал несколько способов, но не получается адекватно остановить и запустить после наведения/вывода курсора на/за область блока

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста - https://jsfiddle.net/knvnckbz/4/

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div'),
  addTimeout = null,
  removeTimeout = null,
  classNames = [];

div.addEventListener('mouseover', addClass);
div.addEventListener('mouseout', removeClass);

function addClass() {
  clearTimeout(removeTimeout);
  var className = 'number_' + (classNames.length);
  div.classList.add(className);
  classNames.push(className);
  addTimeout = setTimeout(addClass, 1000);
}

function removeClass() {
  clearTimeout(addTimeout);
  var className = classNames.pop();

  if (!className) return;

  div.classList.remove(className);

  removeTimeout = setTimeout(removeClass, 1000);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
.number_1 {
  background: red;
}
.number_2 {
  background: blue;
}
.number_3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```